# Get PHP variable after successful jquery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code in a html page:

```
$('#save-image-php').click(function() {
$.post( "php/save_image.php", { 
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(json.productID);
}
});
});
```

And I have a php page save_image.php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(
$arrayID = array('productID' => $productID)
);
```

The alert won't display the value of the product ID. Any guesses as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to do `$.parseJSON(data)` because it is already done automatically. `data` is an object at this point, not a string. So just do `alert(data.productID)`;

Comment: As far as i understand if you say `dataType: "json"` you don't need `parseJSON`

Answer (score 0):

Your php code should look like

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'productID' => $productID
));
```

EDIT:
As mentioned, you should also remove $.parseJSON(). That actually might be what's giving you problems

EDIT2:
You syntax may be wrong. Try using $.post this way:

```
$.post('test.php', '', function(data) {
    alert(data.productID);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: I edited the php code, and took out parsejson and still no luck :/

Comment: Hmm, can you see what gets returned inside your data variable in your success function?

Comment: try to do `console.log(data);` and check what comes in console?

Comment: Wait, you might have the wrong syntax for $.post. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I've updated my answer with a jquery post example using your code